# deformed head after rigging

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

this is my first Time rigging and doing weight painting and I can't figure out this issue.
in my weight paint the whole head is red but when I go to move it in pose mode its still deforming. I've tried reseting it and trying again but It is still having issues[image]

Comment: bri, it looks like you have some other IK bones in your rigging.  Be sure that for the IK bones, you have Deform unchecked (bone properties).  Even through your weight paint for the "head FK" bone may be all red, if your other IK bone was deform set, and it is also affecting part of your character, you will get these distortions.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/drzjj4e3kwnjsay/cap.png?dl=0   best of luck to you in learning blender.

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/